# Title for mapreduce file output

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am developing an MapReduce based app and I want to add  to my output file (txt file) title from inside the process.
this is my current out put:

Streptococcus_suis2 41581

Streptococcus_suis3 41581

this is how I want the file look like:

Sample1

Streptococcus_suis2 41581

Streptococcus_suis3 41581

Anybody has an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using the `TextOutputFormat` and writing your data with a call to `context.write(key,value);`
from your reducer of type

```
MyReducer extends Reducer<InKey,InValue,Text,LongWritable>
```

You may override the `setup` method of your reducer:

```
@Override
protected void setup(Context context) {
    context.write(new Text("Sample1"),null);
}
```

and call context.write with null as second parameter to add the header line to your output files.